# iOS - Why same asset has different assetURLs?

Tags: ios, iphone

I am working on iOS to fetch assets (photos and videos) from the default Cameral Roll album and Recently Added album by using the following commands:

```
PHFetchResult *CameraRollAssetsFetchResults = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithOptions:options];
PHFetchResult *recentlyAddedAssetsFetchResults = [PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithType:PHAssetCollectionTypeSmartAlbum subtype:PHAssetCollectionSubtypeSmartAlbumRecentlyAdded options:nil];
```

There is a photo in both albums and I tried to use assetURL to de-duplicate.

However, the same photo has two different assetURLs when it was fetched, from Camera Roll and Recently Added albums respectively. How can it be? Any suggestions? Are there any ways to recognize the same asset fetched from different albums?

Answer (score 0):

> has two different assetURLs when it was fetched from Camera Roll and Recently Added albums respectively? How can it be?

Because the URL includes the place where the asset is to be found. It's just like an alias or symlink; two symlinks may be different, pointing to resources in different folders, yet point to what is ultimately one and the same resource.

> Are there any ways to recognize the same asset fetched from different albums?

If they are truly the same, their `localIdentifier` values would be the same.

Comment: I just tried .phAsset.localIdentifier but still cannot recognize :(

Comment: If they have different identifiers, the library must consider them different assets...